# How to understand the "v-type" argument error described in xparse package documentation?

Tags: verbatim, xparse, documentation

I'm getting myself familiar with the LaTeX3 new way of composing a customized command using the `xparse` package.

However, I don't quite understand what does this line means from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf):

```
v Reads an argument “verbatim”, between the following character and its next occurrence,
in a way similar to the argument of the LATEX 2ε command \verb. Thus
a v-type argument is read between two identical characters, which cannot be any
of %, \, #, {, } or ␣. The verbatim argument can also be enclosed between braces,
{ and }. A command with a verbatim argument will produce an error when it
appears within an argument of another function.
```

I thought the "argument in another function" case looks like:

```latex
\SomeCommand{\CustomizedCommand+parameter+}
```

But when I try this example (MWE, using `XeLaTeX`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{mv}{
    (#1)(#2)
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\TestA}{v}{
    <#1>
}
\begin{document}
\TestA+\Test{first}|second|+ \par
\TestA{\Test{first}|second|}
\end{document}
```

It output:

```
<\Test{first}|second|>
<\Test{first}|second|>
```

Looks like it just simply doesn't execute the inner command. And there is no error thrown, which is as expected.

So I think there must be something wrong with my understanding, and I put it here just looking forward to a nice discussion with you. Thanks!

---

**Besides**, I tried to use `pdfLaTeX` compiler instead of `XeLaTeX`. But the output was (same source):

```
¡“Test–first ̋—second—¿
¡“Test–first ̋—second—¿
```

For this, I have no idea either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v` type reads the argument “verbatim”, which means roughly “everything is a normal character”, so `\TestA+\Test{first}|second|+` reads everything between the two `+` as characters (a `•` separates two tokens):

```latex
\•T•e•s•t•{•f•i•r•s•t•}•|•s•e•c•o•n•d•|
```

rather than the usual:

```latex
\Test•{•f•i•r•s•t•}•|•s•e•c•o•n•d•|
```

which means that in there `\Test` is no longer a command, but just 5 characters.

As promised in the documentation, you get more or less the same with `\verb`:

```latex
\verb+\Test{first}|second|+
```

Also note that the `xparse` documentation for the `v` argument warns you that:

> A command with a verbatim argument will produce an error when it appears within an argument of another function.

so using a command with a `v` argument in the argument of any other command is not supported.

---

As for the output, pdfLaTeX uses by default the legacy OT1 encoding, which has a limited number of (128) characters, so the OT1 Computer Modern font doesn't have `\` and a bunch of others.  If you use the T1 encoding or a typewriter (`\ttfamily`) font, it will show up correctly:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for pdfTeX only
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\cmd[1]{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\TestA}{v}{
    <#1>
}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\TestA+\Test{first}|second|+ \par
\TestA{\Test{first}|second|}
\cmd{\TestA{\Test{first}|second|}} % ERROR: \TestA inside \cmd
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With your answer, I also find `\textbf{\verb+AAAA+}` throwing error with almost same reason. I've got a good point to learn, thanks again!

Comment: @DavidHans Yes, it uses a slightly different mechanism (for instance, with `\textbf{\TestA+AAAA+}` there is no error), but the principle is the same.  Verbatim is... complicated :-)